# Word order with "Wer ..." subclause

Tags: grammar, word-order

> Wer eine ausgezeichnete Ausbildung zum Ingenieur bekommen möchte, studiert hier.

This is the usual word order when we have a "Wer ..." subclause.

Can we say the following?

> Hier studiert wer eine ausgezeichnete Ausbildung zum Ingenieur bekommen möchte.

What would be the differences between the two sentences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can. However, you still need the comma.

> "Hier studiert, wer eine ausgezeichnete Ausbildung zum Ingenieur bekommen möchte."

This is a way of phrasing that puts immediate emphasis on the university being vital to receiving an excellent education as an engineer.

A person involved in marketing would choose to phrase exactly this way in order to promote a university.

The other way around it basically means the same thing, but instead emphasizes on the quality of the education.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your second sentence is correct. It should have a comma, though:

> Hier studiert**,** wer eine ausgezeichnete Ausbildung zum Ingenieur bekommen möchte.